# Eigen::MatrixXd index permutation

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

Is there any possible way of creating a view to an `Eigen::MatrixXd` matrix in which the indexes are permuted? For example, if the view is named matView and the original matrix is named mat, then `matView(i,j)` should actually refer to the `mat(f(i),f(j))`, where `f(index)` is some function that maps an index to another. I'm asking this because I am writing a quantum computing library and would like to perform index permutation without actually moving the elements of the matrix in the memory (same way as MATLAB does). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you might be looking for is the transpose operation provided by Eigen in the BaseMatrix class. As the [Eigen documentation indicates](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Transpose.html) The *transpose* and *adjoint* methods in the *BaseMatrix* class return an object representing the transpose operation, not the matrix transpose itself.

Regards.